# Direct and indirect reference errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've just migrated my solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015.  It consists of 3 DLL projects (all C#) and a web application project (VB.Net).

Despite compiling correct and being able to run/debug the code, Visual Studio 2015 keeps complaining that...

> BC32207   The project currently contains references to more than one version of 'xxx.dll', a direct reference to version 2.0.5987.24747 and an indirect reference to version 2.0.5987.24748. Change the direct reference to use version 2.0.5987.24748 (or higher) of xxx.dll.

This doesn't just happen with the one dll, but can happen with any of the 3... there doesn't appear to be any pattern to which one it complains about.

I can continue working, but it's very distracting having lots of "errors" (highlighted with red wavey-underline) in the code which aren't actually errors.

Without locking the version number down, how can I stop Visual Studio picking up on the multiple references?

For the record, I have `cleaned` the solution when in `Release` mode but I still get it after compiling in `Debug` mode.

Comment: I assume you have the source code for all 3 projects. Check that the project build order is still correct. It sounds like one project may be getting built twice. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/10/13/did-you-know-how-to-change-the-build-order-for-your-solution-333/  Another option is to delete the solution file and create a new one and re-add the projects, maybe something got twisted up in the migration.

Comment: @Murray - yes, all projects are written by me, they all contain source code.  Will try create new solution now

Comment: Make sure you make Project References to the dependent projects, DONT pick them up from an output (e.g. bin) folder.

Comment: @Murray - struggling to get a new solution working with the projects... will get back to you, but might be while. Thanks for your help

Comment: Good luck. Check the link I posted to set up the dependencies.